# HP Laserjet takes serveral seconds to start printing

Tags: windows-10, performance, printing, hp-laserjet

The printer in question is a HP Laserjet 1320.
It is connected over a network with a parallel port print server and it uses "hp Laserjet 1320 PCL 6" driver. For port, the network address is entered.

When printing from a specific Windows 10 Pro (version 1709) machine, once every few weeks, the printer becomes extremely slow to respond. Printing still works, however, instead of it taking 2 seconds, it then takes 10 seconds. When the issue appears, it only happens on a single machine.

Restarting the machine or restarting the print spooler service does not help. The issue appears regardless of the application that's doing the printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution to restore previous performance doesn't make much sense, but I've had success with it twice so far.

1. Open Print Management (In start menu: printmanagement.msc)
2. Open "All Printers"
3. Right click on the affected printer, select "Properties"
4. In the "Port" tab, select a different port from the list and then pick the original one again
5. Press "Apply", then "OK"

The printer should have its performance restored immediately, without having to restart any software you're printing from.